# How to fix function to where it allows the next function to correctly compute?

Tags: javascript, html

hope everyone is doing well. I am new to JavaScript and trying to do a little exercise but having trouble. When I load the page, and click the Blue button, the orange text and red text disappear like I want to, but if I click the Red button after. All of it disappears. I am trying to create something where if I click on one of the colors, the colors that isn't clicked on disappear and only the colored text remains. I want to be able to do it endlessly.

I've tried various websites but haven't been able to get the help I want.

JavaScript

```
function blueChange() {
var firstHidden = document.getElementById('orange');
firstHidden.style.display = "none";
var secondHidden = document.getElementById('red');
secondHidden.style.display = "none";


}
function redChange() {
var thirdHidden = document.getElementById('blue');
thirdHidden.style.display = "none";
var fourthHidden = document.getElementById('orange');
fourthHidden.style.display = "none";
}



document.getElementById('blueButton').addEventListener("click", 
blueChange);
document.getElementById('redButton').addEventListener("click", 
redChange);
```

HTML

```
<section>
    <button id="blueButton">
        Blue
    </button>
    <button id="orangeButton">
        Orange
    </button>
    <button id="redButton">
        Red
    </button>
</section>

<section id="allParagraphs">
    <p style="color:orange" id="orange" class="colors">
        So far, authorities are still in the process of collecting
        information, and details on exact numbers or the cause of the die off
        have been scarce. Several turtle species live in the area—hawksbills,
        leatherbacks, olive ridleys, and green turtles.
    </p>
    <p style="color:red" id="red" class="colors">
        In both of these previous cases, red tide was found to be the
        cause of the turtles' deaths. "Red tide" is a term that commonly refers
        to when colonies of algal blooms grow out of control. Sometimes,
        depending on the specific organisms and conditions, they can become toxic
        for marine life. Flair ups can occur in fresh and salt water, and they
        can be exacerbated by runoff from chemicals like pesticides or untreated
        sewer water. For turtles, ingesting the toxic blooms can be deadly.
    </p>
    <p style="color:blue" id="blue" class="colors">
        Mike Liles has lived in El Salvador for the past decade working
        on turtle conservation as the director of the country's branch of the
        Eastern Pacific Hawksbill Initiative. From his sources on the ground,
        Liles has learned that as many as 300 additional dead turtles may have
        been found in an area called Isla Tasajara 30 miles west of Jiquilisco
        Bay. El Salvador's environmental ministry has yet to confirm this.
    </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you never reset the color that matches the button. So for example, when you click the Blue button, that correctly hides the Orange and Red text. Then if you click the Red button, again, it correctly hides the Orange and Blue text. But the Red text is still hidden from the first time you clicked the Blue button -- you never un-hide that text!

Try adding code to each event listener to reset the color that matches the button clicked. For example:

```
function blueChange() {
    var firstHidden = document.getElementById('orange');
    firstHidden.style.display = "none";
    var secondHidden = document.getElementById('red');
    secondHidden.style.display = "none";

    // reset blue.
    var blueElement = document.getElementById('blue');
    blueElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: really appreciate your answer, sorry for being a noob :)

Answer (score 1):

As explained in srk's answer above, you need to reset the display property each time.

In addition, i would suggest that you create a general function like bellow:

```
function toggleColorDisplay(color){
let colors = ['red', 'orange', 'blue']; // you can add any color you want
colors.forEach(col => {
let elem = document.getElementById(color);
if(col == color) elem.style.display = 'block' // or whatever the original display property is
else elem.style.display = 'none';
})}
```

Then you call that function:

```
document.getElementById('blueButton').addEventListener("click", function() {
toggleColorDisplay('blue');
};
```

Repeat this call for each button, just change the argument to the appropriate color